# Get unique ids for updated timeline items

Tags: google-mirror-api

When you schedule an update for a timeline item do you get a unique item id or the same one?

My question is can you chain multiple updates after one another and get unique ids? https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/update

The current result isn't clear in the current documentation.

This way if a user stops the process you can easily access all the future timeline items and delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same one.

If you update a `timelineItem` via [update](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/update) or [patch](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/patch), the item which is returned will have the same `ID` that you passed in.